# Is object-based representation of the observation space feasible?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python, environment, state-spaces

I just started working on a DRL project from scratch. The state of each episode can be expressed as a state set $S=(S^A, S^B, S^C, S^D)$. Each subset is a feature set of a constituent component of the environment, say, $S^A=(a_1, a_2, a_3)$. To model components, I decided to create four pythonic classes with attributes as features. For example, `class A` is like:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2, a3): 
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2
        self.a3 = a3
```

Each class has some methods that help in the interaction with other components (classes) and is used in the environment's `step function` to generate actions.

I am going to create one instance of `class A`, 10 instances of `class B`, 20 instances of `class C`, and a random number of between 1-10 instances of `class D` at the beginning of each episode. So, my observation includes 33-42 states of entities.

As far as I know, the observation space is usually encoded in n-dimensional arrays as it is in OpenAI Gym. **Is it possible, feasible, or considered good practice to store instances as a sub-state of the whole observation space?** In my case, it would be like storing 33-42 instances in an array (list) of 33-42 elements.

Thanks for your time and suggestions!